# Uploading a external squeeze page within WP

Tags: blog, ftp

I'm not a developer but I'm trying to find my own way around and learning as I go along. I have a prebuild squeeze page and trying to FTP it to my site but I have learned that I don't have access to the CPanel which basically stop me from using any FTP clients.

Long story short, I need to upload this squeeze page onto my site and I have no clue how to do that without FTP. I know WP is very flexible due to the numerous plug-ins so I believe there should be away to do so within WP.

Is there a way in for me?

The longer I wait, the more I'm losing out and it is delaying my Blog post which is dependent on this page.

Please assist...

Regards 
Ghost

Comment: Have you tried searching the [WordPress plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/plugins/)? [Asking for plugin recommendations is off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Does your hosting give you _no_ ability to upload files at all? That is highly peculiar. While it is interesting technically how to upload arbitrary thing using installed WordPress, it's not too practical under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do when you want to install a new WordPress theme is to login to your site admin page. Once there, go to **Appearance** -> **Themes**. Here, you will see all the themes you have currently installed in your application. To add another one, simply click on the **add new** button, click on the **Upload** link at the top of the page. Now, click the **Choose File** button, select the archive of your theme (you need to have your theme folder as zipped file) from your local computer and press the **Install Now** button. In few seconds, WordPress will upload and extract the theme archive for you. All you need to do next is to press the **Activate** link under the message for successful theme installation.